# SEO - META Tags and Google

Tags: seo

I just found out that Google recently decided to start using their own "title" when they display their search results. Also, after checking Yahoo and Bing I saw that the way they are displaying their results are the same but in completely different way than Google.

I guess my question would be, if there is an actual "correct" way of adding titles to my pages in order for Google to display what I want them to and this way get the same results with Yahoo/Bing that are currently using the page's title as a search result (sometimes they pick up the first  tag and use it as title).

Any recommendations or links to follow for more studying would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing you can really do about it. Google will choose what title to display based on criteria they have not made public. This usually is the page's title as found in the `<title>` tag but if Google feels a different title better summarizes the page's content they may choose to display something else.

You can try to change your page titles to better reflect the page's content and see if that helps.

Comment: That is what I was thinking to do. The thing is, it will take time until the spiders get my new title. Also, I found out that titles can be generated based on the user's search words...Thanks for your response though

Answer (score 0):

Using optimal keyword prominency in meta tags according to guidelines... and Google will pick up your meta tags. See our news portal's source and metas (keywords: hírek, választás 2014, etc.): http://valasztas2014.hir24.hu/